# Make one section of page scrollable while maintaining heights of subsections

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I want to make only one section of my webpage scrollable. Suppose this section is called Section A.

Right now, all my heights are percentage-based, and the way I have it is: Section A is the bottom 70% of the entire webpage, and on the left half of my webpage. Section A is vertically split into two sections, with the top section (call it Section X) taking the top 70% of Section A's height, and the bottom section (call it Section Y) taking the bottom 30% of Section A's height.

I want to add another subsection to Section A, but I want to keep the heights the same for Section A's existing subsections. So I would want something like a 70%-30%-50% split in height, where the third 50% section (call it Section Z) overflows, and causes Section A to scroll vertically. Section X and Section Y should have the same height as before. So when the page loads initially, I want to see only Section X and Section Y within Section A, just like before, except now if I scroll downwards in Section A, I will see Section Z beneath. The rest of the webpage shouldn't scroll with Section A.

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement this. Do I have to get rid of percentage-based heights altogether? I've tried experimenting with overflow-y, and different ways of specifying height, but have not been successful. The other links I've found on StackOverflow have also not given me a solution.

Sorry for explaining so much with words -- the existing HTML and CSS is a lot so I'm not sure how I'd concisely paste it here. Let me know if there is anything I can do to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for here (without seeing code) is the overflow: scroll property.

Check out this page which gives a good description:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Comment: Right but within the overflow element, how do I get the heights of the subsections that I want?